# Why is the indefinite article used with a plural noun?

Tags: grammatical-number

I don't understand why an indefinite article is used with a plural noun in this sentence:

> Für meine Schwester habe ich einen Berliner Bären gekauft.

Even the indefinite article *ein* ist conjugated in the masculine form. Wouldn't it be correct to say *Bär* instead of *Bären*?

[image]

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Baer_Raubtier#grammatik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for which the correct fom is : einen BärEN , is because Bär is a type of masculine noun, that follows the [N-Declination](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/n-deklination.html). (Only masculine nouns do this.)

Only a small group of masculine nouns gains an extra "n", when used as object of the phrase (Genitiv, Dativ, Akkusativ). To this group belong many professions (but not all) and animals (but not all) .

Examples are: der Polizist, der Falke, der Kollege, der Student ....

So, you would say: Der Student ist schön. (no -n, because Student is subject (Nominativ)).

But: Ich habe einen KollegeN/StudenteN/ FalkeN. (Akkusativ)

Or: Ich war mit dem KollegeN/StudenteN/ FalkeN im Park. (Dativ)

Answer (score 12):

It is not a plural form. *Bären* is the accusative singular of *Bär* (see [canoonet](http://www.canoonet.eu/inflection/b%C3%A4r:N:M:Tier)). Accordingly, since in the case of *kaufen* the thing that is purchased is in accusative case, you cannot replace *Bären* (accusative singular) with *Bär* (nominative singular).

Answer (score 3):

Bär is a 'weak masculine noun' which means that the nominative singular is 'Bär' but all other forms are 'Bären'.

Comment: Are there also nouns like this?

Comment: @Steve There's a list [here](https://www.vistawide.com/german/grammar/german_nouns03.htm)

Answer (score 3):

In grammars and dictionaries you find the noun *Bär* classified as a 'weak' masculine noun. Those nouns are declined by adding *-(e)n* in all cases except the nominative singular. According to this, *Bär* should be declined this way:

- N  der Bär,     die Bären
- A  den Bären,   die Bären
- D  dem Bären,   den Bären
- G  des Bären,   der Bären

So, "*einen Berliner Bären gekauft*" is the regular accusative singular form, since '*kaufen*', as *johnl* said, puts the object of purchase as an accusative.

In real life however you will stumble across phrases like these:

> F.A.Z. Schulportal - Auf den Bär gekommen
>
> Interessantes über den Bär. (biologie-schule.de)
>
> Wir jagen den Bär. (neuulmer-singewettstreit.de)

'*Bär*' is one of the nouns that tend to be declined more and more often in the 'normal' way, that means as a 'strong' noun:

- N  der Bär,     die Bären
- A  den Bär,     die Bären
- D  dem Bär,     den Bären
- G  des Bärs,    der Bären

This is not accepted in standard German but quite common in spoken every day German. So I understand that Steve misinterpreted *Bären* as a plural form.

In *Hammer's German Grammar and Usage*, 6th edition (1) you can read on page 34:

"**The singular endings of weak masculine nouns are often dropped in colloquial German** i.e. they have the 'regular' forms: *den Bär, des Bärs, dem Bär*, especially with endingless forms of the accusative and dative singular. In principle, this usage is considered non-standard and incorrect, especially in writing, but it is clearly becoming more widespread." I was surprised to read in black and white what I had assumed independently before looking it up in this book.

Concerning the genitive forms' frequency (*des Bären / des Bärs* and other irregular genitives) there is a study from Wolfgang Krischke that you can read on the [internet](https://bop.unibe.ch/linguistik-online/article/view/289/411).

There may be a second reason for not declining "Berliner Bär" in the traditional way: As a 'Maskottchen' the Berlin Bear bears his **name** like a title, and the only ending for names is the genitive -s. For me, "einen Berliner Bären kaufen" would be rather a real bear from Berlin than a symbolic or allegoric figurine.

Das letzte möchte ich kurz auf Deutsch ergänzen, weil ich mich auf Englisch nur notdürftig ausdrücken kann. Für mein Alltagsdeutsch wäre wie gesagt "*für die kleine Schwester einen Stoffbär gekauft*" die nicht markierte sprechsprachliche Standardvariante. "*Ich habe ihr einen Stoffbären gekauft*" wäre für mich tendenziell ähnlich geziert, wie ein Genitiv nach '*wegen*' sehr vielen - vermutlich den meisten - im gesprochenen Deutsch inzwischen vorkommt, obwohl die 'Gralshüter des Genitivs' (hab ich hier irgendwo gelesen, passt hier gut) unverdrossen daran festhalten, dass auch dort immer nur der Genitiv zulässig sei. Bei dem *gekauften Stoffbären* würde ich denken, *hui, da versucht aber einer sich superkorrekt auszurücken!* Nun denn.

Was den *Berliner Bär* als Wappentier und als solchen angeht, so stellt er eine Art Wortmarke dar, bei der das Bezeichnende teilweise in den Status eines Eigennamens übergeht, vergleichbar dem *Goldenen Bären*, dem Filmpreis der Berlinale. Solche Wortmarken leisten möglicherweise gegenüber einer Deklination einen gewissen Widerstand - wie "*Alter Markt*" in Köln -, den genau zu bestimmen eine eigene Untersuchung wert wäre.

Ein letzter Blick auf Google-Trefferzahlen, von denen allerdings alle größer als ein paar hundert nur geringen Aussagewert haben und allenfalls als Richtgrößen zu verstehen sind:

- "einen Bären" 346.000
- "einen Bär" 103.000 (!, *das wäre ziemlich viel*)
- "einen Berliner Bären" 1.920
- "einen Berliner Bär" 93 (*das ist ziemlich wenig*)

Aber Google bezieht sich naturgemäß auf geschriebenes Deutsch, Aussagen über gesprochenes Deutsch lassen sich daraus nur sehr bedingt ableiten.

---

(1) Martin Durrell, *Hammer's German Grammar and Usage*, sixth edition, London/New York 2017

Comment: It's *des Bären*, not *des Bärs*.

Comment: @RHa: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/B%C3%A4rs

Comment: You could have first answered the question before going into discussing language change.

Comment: @Carsten S: That's correct, but the normative and correct point of view had already been displayed by _johnl_ and _Jacob Lee-Hart_, I didn't want to write it down a third time. I just wanted to give a supplement explaining _Steve's_ misunderstanding.

Comment: That makes what you have written a comment, not an answer. You know that that’s not how this site works.

Comment: @Carsten S: Unfortunately I cannot delete my posting and shift in into a comment.

Comment: @RalfJoerres, I don’t think that it should be a comment, it contains too much useful information for that. Maybe you could just reorganise it a bit to start with an answer and then add detail. Sorry to be such a bother.

Comment: "This is not accepted in standard German but quite common in spoken every day German (...)." I believe, this is incorrect. The correct for is indeed  : Ich möchte einen Bären. Because Bär is a noun that follows N-Deklination. https://mein-deutschbuch.de/n-deklination.html.  Kindly see my answer below.

Comment: @rainer: If _den Bären_ is the only correct form, so why is it that simple to find so many examples bringing in _den Bär_ and among them even a quotation from the FAZ? It took me two minutes to find the examples. By the way: What people really **say** cannot be proven by grammars that are based on corpora of written German. You have to ask Germann native speakers without influencing their answers, perhaps by showing a photo of a cuddly bear and asking: "How would ou say you bought this for your little nephew?"

Comment: @RalfJoerres, I am a native German speaker and also teach the language to foreigners. I am sure correct written form is : Ich habe einen Bären. But, as you point out, the use of spoken language can differ from the written one. If it's in the FAZ, maybe the author or editor didn't notice the mistake. It's a quite subtle and common one, that also most natives probably commit.

Comment: @rainer: Thank you for commenting my ideas. I think your point of view is a normative one, and this is perfectly okay. For me the changes in language use are much more interesting. What I did was to ask myself what I would say in a comparable situation. I didn't know the answer before, but being honest to myself I must admit that in many contexts _den Bär_ sounds much more natural for me than _den Bären_. I think I'm not the only person having this 'feeling'. So, for me, the FAZ writer didn't make a mistake, he just wrote down what he felt to be correct according to his linguistic experience.

Comment: @RalfJoerres, thanks for commenting back on mine. You are making a good point here, when you say that the FAZ writer didn't make a mistake, he just wrote down what he felt to be correct according to his linguistic experience. I haven't thought about it this way. Would you say that when someone writes something, he/ she need not care too much about the grammatical correctness? Or do you believe that common usage of language is more important than grammar norms?

Comment: @rainer: What people call grammatial correctness is in fact difficult to define. Many mistakes are obvious, but there is also a wide range of variability and with it acceptability in many grammatical fields, and the 'weak' declension of nouns is one of them. Correct, for me, is what a "kompetenter Sprecher" of German would qualify as a correct German expression. Grammars and dictionaries are relatively slow in reducing to rules a language's new tendencies, but language change exists and grammars have to take this into account - afterwards. As a last consequence, one can only know ...

Comment: ... (one can only know) by oneself, if a certain expression is correct German or not - on condition that he is a competent German speaker. So, indeed, what Grammars say is less important, but it is essential for learning and understanding a language. So called "kompetente Sprecher des Deutschen" even don't know the rules, but they can assess sentences as wrong or correct. Martin Durrell and myself, we judged "einen Bär" as - relatively - correct, and some other people joined our opinion. Those who don't agree are perhaps not aware of the reality of non-declined forms of _Bär. Aber die gibt es_